# BS4 find_all with tags in space

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

How to use `bs4` with `find_all` with the class tag with space?

```
container = containers[0]
product_container = container.find_all('div',{'class': 's-item-container'})
product_name = product_container.find_all('div', {'class': 'a-fixed-left-grid-col'})
print (product_name)
```

the div class tag is "`a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right`", how can i deliver the `find_all` functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the class name with spaces as the value for `class` if the tags you want have the format `<tag class="classname1 classname2 ...">`.

```
soup.find_all('tag', {'class': 'classname1 classname2 ...'})
```

You can also use a list of classes:

```
soup.find_all('tag', {'class': ['class1', 'class2']})
```

But, the second method will match all the tags of the following type:

- `class="class1"`
- `class="class2"`
- `class="class1 class2"`
- `class="class2 class1"` (this is exactly same as above)

Answer (score 0):

I am using select now to locate class with multiple tags

container.select('div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right')

Many thanks for all your helps.